# GWT Activity and Editor Framework

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp

I´ve been working on some small projects using GWT MVP framework + GWT
Editors framework. I have Views interfaces with fields declared like:

```
 @Path("field")
 IsEditor<ValueBoxEditor<Long>> getField();
```

Views implementations look like this:

```
@UiField
   IsEditor<ValueBoxEditor<Long>> field;
public IsEditor<ValueBoxEditor<Long>> getField(){
   return field;
}
```

In my Activitys I have referances to correspond Views and when I have
to do(in Activity) something like this:

```
view.getField.setEnable(true);
```

I have to do cast to

```
((ValueBoxBase<Long>)view.getField()).setEnable(true);
```

After that I can't test this unit, because in my test I define behaviour of View to return Mock `(IsEditor<ValueBoxEditor<Long>>)` on `view.getFiled()` as result I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.editor.client.IsEditor$
$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$e8c00c36 cannot be cast to
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ValueBoxBase
```

What is best practiece to call Views components methods from Activity
without doing casting?

Answer (score 0):

Cast to HasEnabled instead of ValueBoxBase.

Comment: asdjava.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.editor.client.IsEditor$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ea68060b cannot be cast to com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasEnabled

Comment: It won’t help with my test, I still have
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.editor.client.IsEditor$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ea68060b cannot be cast to com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasEnabled
I want to find approach how to get widget from object under  IsEditor<ValueBoxEditor<Long>> in Activity without strong casting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ValueBoxEditor adapter method "of":

```
@UiField ValueBoxBase<Long> field;

public ValueBoxEditor<Long> getField(){
   return ValueBoxEditor.of(field);
}
```